# How to hide the navigation buttons in openoffice writer

Tags: openoffice.org, uno

Openoffice writer has a set of navigation buttons (up, select, down) shown below the vertical scrollbar.

- I wish to remove this as my app is [kiosk software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software).
- I only wish to remove the navigation buttons, not the scrollbar.
- I'm trying to remove/hide these programmatically using the [Java UNO bindings](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/java/ref/overview-summary.html). However if there is a solution because of the nature of UNO it should be possible in any language.
- I'm using openoffice 3.3.0

[image: Navigation button]

Things I've tried:

- View settings: The scrollbar can be hidden by setting the property ("ShowVertRuler", false) from the [view settings](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/ViewSettings.html) obtained via XTextDocument => CurrentController => XViewSettingsSupplier => XViewSettings. No similar property exists for the navigation buttons. Interestingly hiding the scrollbar also hides the navigation buttons implying it is all one widget??
- XUIElement access: I've removed other elements like toolbars by obtaining the XLayoutManager via XFrame, iterating over the list of XUIElement and calling XLayoutManager.hideElement() with the ResourceURL for the XUIElement.
- XAccessible access: I have found examples of how to get the scrollbar value by getting an XAccessible reference. See [this thread](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=90841). However it only seems possible to set/get model values using XAccessible, and not affect visibility.
- Looking at documentation for [UNO](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/module-ix.html) and much googling.

I'm only after a pointer in the right direction in terms of the API. I can write any code necessary myself.

Comment: Handling [navigation buttons](http://plan-b-for-openoffice.org/search/index?q=Help,%20navigation%20pane%20showing/hiding) in **openoffice** [Navigation Panel](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=49295)

Comment: this open office source code. [OpenOffice.org Source code](http://www.openoffice.org/dev_docs/source/get_source.html) manually you have to remove from source code recompile

Comment: Try this link, it might be of some help. http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/Administration_Guide/Restricting_functionality

Answer (score -1):

As Openoffice is a free software, you can access the source code and remove the line which displays the navigation button to create a customized version of Openoffice without this button.